# Problems with Registering User

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So, I have a backend auth which is showing me the Userdata in the postman and as well in the Mongo. I had an error in the console  `xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register 404 (Not Found)` which I think I fixed by adding ""http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register", instead of just `api/auth/register` in the post method, but now when I try to register I am getting this error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`. If someone would tell me why is this showing, and how to I fix it, I would be grateful. Thanks

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


const Register = ({ history }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmpassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const registerHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const config = {
      header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    if (password !== confirmpassword) {
      setPassword("");
      setConfirmPassword("");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setError("");
      }, 5000);
      return setError("Passwords do not match");
    }

    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register",
        {
         
          username,
          email,
          password,
        },
        config
      );

      localStorage.setItem("authToken", data.token);

      history.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.response.data.error);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setError("");
      }, 5000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="register-screen">
      <form onSubmit={registerHandler} className="register-screen__form">
        <h3 className="register-screen__title">Register</h3>
        {error && <span className="error-message">{error}</span>}
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="name">Username:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            required
            id="name"
            placeholder="Enter username"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            required
            id="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            required
            id="password"
            autoComplete="true"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            required
            id="confirmpassword"
            autoComplete="true"
            placeholder="Confirm password"
            value={confirmpassword}
            onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Register
        </button>

        <span className="register-screen__subtext">
          Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Comment: debug what await axios.post returns

Answer (score 1):

you need to check for `error.response` existence. Seems like it is undefined in your case.

```js
if (error.response) {
  setError(error.response.data.error);
}
setTimeout(() => {
   setError("");
}, 5000);
```

That will help you with this error `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` but to answer why you're getting `xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register 404 (Not Found)` we need more information. Simply there is no `/api/auth/register` handler on your server.

Comment: So, I don't have any errors, when I check the network in the dev tools I can see user being created, but it is not redirecting me to the home, and when I check in the Applications to see if there are any  cookies I cant see any